# "aufschinden" – in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english

I have a problem with interpreting "aufschinden" in the below context:

> Ich habe mich mit mehreren Benennungen herum versucht und mich nur im letzten Augenblick – und dann vielleicht gar für den allerunglücklichsten aufschinden.

Normally "aufschinden" does mean something like scrape up, but in this context it doesn't fit…

Comment: I tried to find this; it's not listed in DWDS or the public domain dictionaries it links to (e.g. Grimm's DWB). It might help to give a source for the example, in particular a date, since the meaning may be obsolete.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not *entschieden*?

Comment: As it is quoted above, the sentence with *aufschinden* is grammatically wrong.

Comment: You posted quite a number of questions about deciphering of old handwritings in Kurrrent or Sütterlin. If the sentence in your question was deciphered from a letter or some other source, I am absolutely sure that it is *entschieden* instead of *aufschinden* because the corresponding Kurrent-letters are rather similar.

Answer (score 2):

The verb is used grammatically wrong - it would have to read *"[...] aufgeschunden."* That sentence would still be grammatically incorrect, as "für den" references something male or plural, and "Benennung" is female. So to be grammatically correct, the whole sentence would have to read:

*"Ich habe mich mit mehreren Benennungen herum versucht und mich nur im letzten Augenblick – und dann vielleicht gar für **die** allerunglücklichst**e** auf**geschunden**."* (Or the intended meaning is for the author to have 'chosen'(?) more than one appellation)

That sentence, while grammatically correct, does not make much sense "*[...]mich [...] aufgeschunden"* means "i scraped myself up [while doing]".

I would wager this is some transcription error, or an error on part of the author, and the intendent sentence either read:

*"Ich habe mich mit mehreren Benennungen herum versucht und mich nur im letzten Augenblick – und dann vielleicht gar für **die** allerunglücklichst**e** **entschieden**.* ("I tried some apellations, and only at the last moment decided on one - possibly the worst")

or

*"Ich habe mich mit mehreren Benennungen herum versucht und mich nur im letzten Augenblick – und dann vielleicht gar **mit** den allerunglücklichsten auf**geschunden**."* ("I tried around with several appellations, and only in the last moment [decided on some and] fell on my face with them")

Another possibility would be that the answer is in the wider context, and the 'den' refers to some male entity that was mentioned before, and the author relays 'taking a hit for someone' (*'[...]für[...]aufgeschunden'* - 'scraped myself up for [...]') . Still, the form of the verb is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is grammatically wrong. The relevant parts are:

> Ich habe mich aufschinden.

If you use the auxiliary verb *»haben«* then the full verb must be used as participle II:

> Ich habe mich **aufgeschunden.**

This means the same as *»Ich habe mich aufgeschürft«:* »I have scraped«

> Ich bin hingefallen und habe mich dabei aufgeschunden.
> *I fell down and scraped myself in the process.*

So, a grammatically correct version of your sentence is this:

> Ich habe mich mit mehreren Benennungen herum versucht und mich nur im letzten Augenblick – und dann vielleicht gar für den allerunglücklichsten – **aufgeschunden.**
> I have tried around with several designations and only at the last moment - and then perhaps even for the most unfortunate one - I have **scraped** myself.

But this doesn't make any sense.

This sentence makes more sense:

> Ich habe mich mit mehreren Benennungen herum versucht und mich nur im letzten Augenblick – und dann vielleicht gar für den allerunglücklichsten – **entschieden.**
> I have tried several names and only **decided** at the last moment - and then perhaps even for the most unfortunate.

The word **entschieden** already is a participle II. It is the participle II of *»entscheiden«* = to decide.

Is it possible, that you found this sentence in some handwriting and misinterpreted some letters? the prefixes *»ent-«* and *»auf-«* can look quite similar when written by hand, and also the *e* after the *i* can easily be mixed up with *n* especially when written in *Kurrent*.

---

There is another error in this sentence:

> wrong: Ich habe mich **nur** im letzten Augenblick entschieden.
> correct: Ich habe mich **erst** im letzten Augenblick entschieden.

Both sentences translate to this in English:

> I decided **only** at the last moment.

But this is another topic. Obviously this sentence was not written by a German native speaker. Read more about erst/nur here: https://yourdailygerman.com/only-in-german-erst-nur/

Comment: Nice answer! But I do not agree to "Obviously this sentence was not written by a German native speaker."  Also native German speakers may produce flawed texts.

Comment: But the mistakes in that sentence aren't ones a German native speaker would make.